# Can't re-initiate a transaction using the Square Register SDK for Android

Tags: square-connect

Our Android team has been integrating the Register SDK that was announced recently and has run into a couple of issues.

We are seeing some strange behavior when repeatedly initiating a transaction (for example, when there is a failure on the first attempt).

Specifically, while testing with the Square Register app installed but not logged in, starting activity with the `ChargeRequest` intent works as expected the first time: it briefly starts the Register app but then returns the user to the calling app, where the user is notified that he or she is not logged in.

However, if we exit the activity that initiates the Square transaction and start the whole process again, we don't get any response when trying to initiate another Square transaction. It is only when we kill the app, do a cold start, and restart the process that the original (and expected) behavior re-occurs.

Any thoughts or advice here would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I started looking into this and will follow up when I know more. In the meantime, can you confirm that you've always used "startActivityForResult()", and never used just the plain "startActivity()" ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `startActivityForResult()` on an activity instance that is finished, Android switches automatically to a `startActivity()` call and logs the following:

```
startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { act=com.squareup.register.action.CHARGE cmp=com.squareup.eng/com.squareup.ui.ApiActivity (has extras) }
```

The means that the called app cannot return an activity result, and it's hard for the caller to know what's wrong. This is the root problem that was causing the issue here.